# Why is Isotope not adding "left" values to grid-items when displaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have created a layout using flex and it displays fine:

[image]

I then loaded Isotope and the cells-by-row.js layout, both files are loaded.

Then by just setting up isotope:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready( function()  {
        var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            layoutMode: 'cellsByRow',
            cellsByRow: {
                columnWidth: 300,
                rowHeight: 375
            },
        });
    }) 
})( jQuery );
```

The layout just renders vertically because each element is set to position:absolute but the left property is left at zero. I assume Isotope would figure the left value for each element and apply it, but for some reason it is not doing so:

[image]

My stripped-down SASS just in case:

```
#people-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .people-single {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 375px;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid $border-grey;
        color: $dark-blue;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
        ...
    }


}
```

Comment: I can see that when isotope loads it sets the position of the grid to 'relative' and then changes the position of grid-items to 'absolute' which messes up the entire layout. Any idea of why it is doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything I was doing was fine, *except* that the width of the grid needs to be explicitly set.

```
#people-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
->  width: 1120px;
```

After I included that, the left properties were successfully calculated.